# What type is "MyInterface.MyCustomError" in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, data-types, type-casting, custom-errors

I'm toying with the recently introduced custom errors. Here's a mini replica of my set up:

```
interface MyInterface {
    error MyCustomError();
}
```

I'm writing my tests in Solidity and I'd like to use the [expectRevert](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cheatcodes.html) cheatcode (part of HEVM) to test that my implementation contract reverts with `MyCustomError`. Here's what I came up with so far:

```
vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSignature("MyCustomError()"));
```

This works since the `expectRevert` cheatcode is implemented in three different ways:

- `expectRevert()`
- `expectRevert(bytes calldata)`
- `expectRevert(bytes4)`

But using `abi.encodeWithSignature` feels like going in a roundabout way. I tried to reference the custom error directly:

```
vm.expectRevert(MyInterface.MyCustomError);
```

But this doesn't compile, so it follows that `MyCustomError` is neither `bytes` nor `bytes4` when referenced like this. That's fine. But then, what type is it, and could I cast it to either `bytes` or `bytes4`?

Comment: Have you tried `MyInterface.MyCustomError.selector` ?  it should return a bytes4 to identify your error in a relatively readable way.

Comment: Thanks @hroussille, I forgot about the `.selector` member. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually figured out half of the answer on my own by trying to force cast the type to `bytes4`. It seems like `MyInterface.MyCustomError` is of type `function() pure`:

> Explicit type conversion not allowed from "function () pure" to "bytes4".

Note that I compile my code with Solidity `v0.8.13+commit.abaa5c0e`.

The other half was elucidated by @hroussille's tip to use the [`.selector`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html?highlight=selector#function-types) member to access the `bytes4` signature of the `MyCustomError` custom error. The following works:

```
vm.expectRevert(MyInterface.MyCustomError.selector);
```

Side note: I ended making a [suggestion](https://forum.soliditylang.org/t/should-custom-errors-be-given-a-bespoke-type/935) in the Solidity forum to add a bespoke type for custom errors, i.e. something like `error` which would be an alias for `bytes24` (just like `function`).

**Update**: it looks like this is actually a bug in Solidity. Casting `MyInterface.MyCustomError` to `bytes4` should work. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12896) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MyInterface.MyCustomError.selector will return bytes4 but expectRevert expects bytes, so the above would throw an error. But that can be easily fixed using

```
vm.expectRevert(abi.encodePacked(MyInterface.MyCustomError.selector));
```

Comment: What version of `forge` are you using, Diganta?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Its "forge 0.1.0". Am I outdated lol

Comment: @DigantaKalita yup. Visit the [README](https://github.com/gakonst/foundry) for instructions on how to upgrade to the latest version.